# Qt Layered Widget Switch Focus

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I am working with a project which consists of one big widget which has a collection of children widgets.  Two of those children widgets are titled 'File Explorer' and 'Project Explorer'.

Because of the nature of the project, the widgets can be layered on top of each other, causing Qt to auto-tab the widgets, giving the user the opportunity to select either widget.

Example:

[image: Layered Widgets]

I would like to have some segment of code that switches which of these two widgets are on top.  Since I'm working in the main, each is declared as a pointer to the widget in question.

I have tried:

```
mFileExplorer->setFocus();
mFileExplorer->raise();
mFileExplorer->show();
mFileExplorer->setFocus();
```

Even if I hide the first widget with

```
mProjectExploerer->hide();
mProjectExplorer->close();
```

I am still left unable to bring the file explorer to the top.  Would this be possible to do in Qt and if so, how?

Comment: Are you looking for [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I'm dealing with legacy code so I can't switch anything major, and the widgets aren't a part of a QStackedWidget class, they're just independent widgets.

Comment: QStackedWidget has existed for ages, so I'm not buying the "legacy" argument. Why can't you use it to solve your problem?

Comment: QStackedWidget is a class which consists of a collection of widgets and only allows one to be in focus at any given time.  Due to the nature of this project, it is fully feasible that both child widgets listed here (File Explorer and Project Explorer) could be visible at the same time, if the user were to orient them in such a manner.

Comment: Then maybe you are looking for [QDockWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html)? Dunno, just guessing here ;) Not quite sure what yyou really want.

Comment: Yeah sorry if the question is a bit unclear.  I have these two widgets which can be docked one on top of the other, but are referenced as pointers to child widgets.  I want to know if there is a way to dynamically switch which of the two are on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two `QWidget`s `mFileExplorer` and `mProjectExplorer` are both already associated with their own `QDockWidget` then I suspect you'll need to perform the `raise` operation on the `QDockWidget` itself.

Given a function such as <sup>[1]</sup> ...

```
QDockWidget *find_dock_widget_for (QWidget *w)
{
  while (w) {
    if (auto *dw = dynamic_cast<QDockWidget *>(w))
      return dw;
    w = w->parentWidget();
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

you should be able to do, for example...

```
if (auto *dock_widget = find_dock_widget_for(mFileExplorer)) {
  dock_widget->raise();
  dock_widget->setFocus();
}
```

---

[1] Note that `find_dock_widget_for` may be overkill here.  The tests I've done suggest that the `QDockWidget` is always the immediate parent of the `QWidget` it manages but I can't find any documentation that guarantees that.

Comment: I think you've struck upon exactly what I was missing:  I was trying to affect the pointers to the child widgets when I should have been trying to affect the docked widgets that were created.  My only concern with this answer is that when I call it verbatim from another method (i.e. 'tabFileExplorer') I get a 'Undefined reference to MainWindow::find_dock_widget_for(QWidget*)'.  Its declaration in the header and cpp is acceptable, but apparently my program doesn't like when it was used

Comment: As presented `find_dock_widget_for` is just a free function -- not necessarily intended to be a member of `MainWindow` or any other class.  Not sure if that helps.